# Minecraft is very slow in Ubuntu

Tags: minecraft

Brand new to Ubuntu, my son and I are frustrated with the lag. Can anyone offer a simple easy to do solution for us?

Comment: Please open a terminal window and execute the command `sudo lspci|grep VGA `.  You can then copy and paste the results of that command into your question, so that we can see which video card you have in your system

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a graphics driver issue. make sure to install the appropriate drivers for your graphics card.

Comment: New users such as the Op described themselves, will likely need guidance in choosing what video drivers they will need.

Comment: Go to settings, then Additional Drivers, then select the recommended driver and click Apply.